# wp_head not output plugins javascripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

`wp_head` output only styles.

`wp_enqueue_script` is working. I check `$wp_scripts`, its return huge array with all scripts.
Byt wp_head is empty. Any suggestions on this? What to do?

**Code**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" /> 
   <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) 
         wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?> <?php wp_head(); ?> 
   <?php //global $wp_scripts; //var_dump($wp_scripts); ?>
 </head>
```

Comment: can you post the entire script? and you do have it in functions.php right?

Comment: Please do move your question to wordpress dev http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin like the CDN plugin where you can manipulate where the scripts are being added?

- Did you try and disable your plugins one by one to see if any of those are causing the problem?
- Check if wp_debug in the wp-config.php is set to false. if it is set it to true to check if you get an error or warning.

Paste an example of your template where wp_head is being used that will help.

Comment: Site http://test.moynepal.com/ wp wersion is 3.8.1
I disable all plugins one by one, byt not see the problem.
Wp_debug is false.

Comment: <code>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php
//global $wp_scripts;
//var_dump($wp_scripts);
?>
</head></code>

Comment: wow euhm :) edit your question and paste it there. will be a bit easier

Comment: what is the result of your var_dump($wpscripts) ??